# Inherited resources parent helpers - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, inherited-resources

In the README for the inherited_resources gem it says the below associations allow the use of helpers such as `parent #=> @task`

```
class CommentsController < InheritedResources::Base
  belongs_to :project {
      belongs_to :file, :message, :task, :polymorphic => true
    }
end
```

What isn't explained is the helper itself. Do we know what this looks like, how it works? It would really help my understanding.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

That gem looks like it's deprecated at this point, but:

What the README is saying is that projects can be a parent to a `:file`, `:message`, or `:task`. Furthermore any of those can be a parent to own `:comment`.

Where this could be useful, is you could call any of those helpers on the `:comment` to get information about its parent. For example you could write a conditional statement to deal with a `:comment` in different ways differently depending on whether it's parent object was a :file or a :task. Here's a random example:

```
render @comment unless @comment.parent_class == Task
```

Comment: Yea, thanks but doesn't answer the question. I'd like to know what the helper itself looks like